# Date literals not working in Salesforce SQL query

Tags: marketing-cloud, sql

I have the following query:

```sql
SELECT First_name, Last_name, Email, Creation_date FROM Random_database
WHERE Creation_date = YESTERDAY
```

I am trying to pull out yesterday's records.

But what I get as a result is the following error: `Error saving the Query field.Invalid column name 'YESTERDAY'.`

Same goes for other date literals like `LAST_WEEK` or `LAST_N_WEEKS:n`.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Marketing Cloud does only offer a reduced scope of SQL functionality in Automation Studio's query activities. To quote from the [MC SQL reference](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_as_sql_reference.htm&type=5):

> SQL support for the SQL Query Activity is based on, but doesn’t
> precisely correspond to, SQL Server 2016 capabilities.

Hence you will need to adjust your query to produce the needed result:

```
SELECT First_name, Last_name, Email, Creation_date FROM Random_database
WHERE Creation_date = DATEADD(day,-1,GETDATE())
```

You should observe, that `GETDATE` will return the system timestamp, which is in CST: Central Standard Time (UTC minus six hours) and is not observing daylight saving time. If your *Creation_date* is stored in a different time zone, you might want to adapt the query even more. Let's assume you store *Creation_date* in UTC:

```
SELECT First_name, Last_name, Email, Creation_date FROM Random_database
WHERE Creation_date = DATEADD(day,-1, SYSDATETIMEOFFSET() AT TIME ZONE 'UTC')
```

Above query will return the current time at same time zone as the one of *Creation_date*.

Comment: I would also consider formatting it from a datetime object to a date object so that you can include all entries in that day and not need to consider the time of day that the report is run as to which records may fall off. `WHERE CAST(Creation_date AS DATE) = CAST(DATEADD(day,-1, SYSDATETIMEOFFSET() AT TIME ZONE 'UTC') AS DATE)`